# Fixed-point: out_Q15 = antilog( in_Q25 ) calculation, avoiding overflow?

Tags: c, signal-processing, fixed-point

I am using a 3rd-party fixed-point `antilog()` function to calculate magnitude from decibel `out_mag = 10^( in_db/20 )`. The `antilog()` takes `Q6.25` format as input, and provides `Q16.15` at output.

The problem is that `antilog()` quickly overflows for some higher dB valus, like 100 dB: `10^( 100/20 ) = 100000`. The highest value `Q16.15` format can have is `2^16-1=65535`, so `100000` doesn't fit.

Is there a trick to avoid the overflow? Prescale input value somehow?

Comment: How about just clamping when converting to Q6.25?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: How about prescaling the input value, i.e.  out_mag_p = 10^(in_db/20/p) and then your final magnitude value becomes:  out_mag = out_mag_p^p

Comment: Well what on Earth do you want to do with a 100000 value if you can't store it? It's not a question for us, it's a question for you, you chose a format that doesn't allow for such large values, why, and then why do you want to store a value so large the format you chose can't take it?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelC. That's a good idea, but I think I found a better solution (see my answer).

Comment: @MichelRouzic Thanks. I didn't choose the formats, they are dictated by the target DSP processor and the 3rd party library.

Comment: Okay in that case just subtract some dB to your input value (let's say 20) so you get a result 10 times lower, for instance. If you use division then you have to use an exponent, which is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. It's a bit tricky.

First, a struct that will hold the output result is needed:

```
typedef struct
{
    q15   v; // Value (within the [MIN, MAX] range for Q16.15).
    int32 s; // Scalefactor.
} q15_t;
```

The idea is to provide result as Output with Scalefactor, where

```
Output = 10^y
Scale  = 2^scalefactor
```

Final output is `Output` shifted left `scalefactor` times.

Here is the math.

Input Q31 format is dB value scaled to [-1,1] with scale being 2^scalefactor.
We need to calculate:

```
Out = 10^(2^scalefactor * in/20.0)

    = 10^(p+y)                  // rewriting as sum
    = 10^p          * 10^y      // to enable exponent multiplication
    = 2^scalefactor * 10^y      // making it power of 2 to be able to just shift
```

This way we are not limited with Q16.15 max value.

We already know `2^scalefactor`, but need to find `y`:

```
2^scalefactor * in = p + y

10^p = 2^scalefactor   =>   p = scalefactor*log(2)   // rewrite as power of 2
2^scalefactor * in = scalefactor*log(2) + y          // replace p
y = 2^scalefactor*in - scalefactor*log(2)            // and find y
```

Calculate y, and feed it into `antilog`.

If input is `100 dB`, then the output magnitude should be `100.000`, which doesn't fit into `Q16.15` format. Using the above solution, `Output = 50.000` (this fits into `Q16.15`!) and `scalefactor = 1`, meaning, the final output is `50.000` shifted to left `1` place. This gives `100.000` as the final result. Depending on your implementation, you might get the same result as `25.000` with `scalefactor = 2`, etc. The idea is there.